# ansible when statement multi-variable substitution

Tags: ansible

I am running a playbook against a dynamic inventory so filtering out different hosts when running the playbook is not something I have done.

That being said, I have skipped/executed certain tasks based on the 'ansible_hostname' fact.   As an example:

```
- name: say 'yes' to every server except server0[12]
  shell: |
    echo 'yes'
  when: '"server01" not in ansible_hostname and
         "server02" not in ansible_hostname'

- name: say 'no' for only server0[12]
  shell: |
    echo 'no'
  when: '"server01" in ansible_hostname or
         "server02" in ansible_hostname'
```

This has worked for me, but its not very sustainable.  I am looking for a way to do this dynamically (variable substitution?).  So for instance I can keep a variable that is a list of [server01,server02] and I can do a for loop of {{ var }} {not in ansible_hostname}.

I am not sure if this is possible or how to accomplish this.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What was your intention for writing a `"server01" in ansible_hostname` condition? Partial match?

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have list of hostname against you want to check:

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars:
    hostname_list: ["server01", "server01", "server01"]

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "test pass"
      when: ansible_hostname not in hostname_list
```